# Binding 'ended' event to sound playing without ID or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html5-audio, tidesdk

I currently have a function setup to play a sounds in TideSDk (an application wrapping program), is as follows: (note: the Ti.Media is an API from TideSDk)

```
function playSound(soundFilePath){
        var s = Ti.Media.createSound(soundFilePath);
        s.play();
        }
```

I then call this function like so: (again don't worry about the Ti.Filesystem, more API)

```
$("#audioMain").click(function() {
         var sound = 'Level1/my_body_here_i_am/audio/f_sentence1.mp3';
         playSound(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getResourcesDirectory(), sound).nativePath())            
            });
```

My problem here is I need to somehow bind the 'ended' event to the sound that plays, it would usually be as easy as:

```
$('#someID').bind('ended', function() {
    //do something
    });
```

But as I can't work with IDs or Classes here I don't know what to bind to. I've tried:

```
sound.addEventListener("ended", function() { }); or
s.addEventListener("ended", function() { });
```

But can't seem to get any of this to work, I'm not sure if I have to include this bind event in the original function.. it's been furstrating me for hours now.

Thanks community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a quick browse of the TideSDK docs it seems as though you can do something like this:

```
function playSound(soundFilePath){
        var s = Ti.Media.createSound(soundFilePath);
        s.play();
        s.onComplete(function(){
           alert("sound finished");
        });
}
```

Have a look here for all the specifics - http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Media.Sound

Looks like calling `Ti.Media.createSound();` returns the `Ti.Media.Sound` object which has the methods `.play()` and the others listed in the link i've provided. Hope this helps

Comment: Worked perfectly, I don;t know how i missed that but yes that was exactly what I was after!